# Improving performance of CLOB insert across a DBLINK in Oracle

Tags: oracle, clob, dblink

I am seeing poor performance in Oracle (11g) when trying to copy CLOBs from one database to another.  I have tried several things, but haven't been able to improve this.

The CLOBs are used for gathering report data.  This can be quite large on a record by record basis.  I am calling a procedure on the remote databases (across a WAN) to build the data, then copying the results back to the database at the corporate headquarters for comparison.  The general format is:

```
CREATE TABLE my_report(the_db VARCHAR2(30), object_id VARCHAR2(30), 
final_value CLOB, CONSTRAINT my_report_pk PRIMARY KEY (the_db, object_id));
```

To gain performance, I accumulate the results for remote sites into remote copies of the table.  At the end of the procedure run, I try to copy the data back.  This query is very simple:

```
INSERT INTO my_report SELECT * FROM my_report@europe;
```

The performance that I am seeing is around 9 rows per second, with an average CLOB size of 3500 bytes.  (I am using CLOBs as this size often goes above 4k, the VARCHAR2 limit.)  For 70,000 records (not uncommon) this takes around 2 hours to transfer.  I have tried using the `create table as select` method, but this gets the same performance.  I also spent more than a few hours tuning SQL*NET, but see no improvement from this.  Changing the Arraysize does not improve the performance (though it can reduce it if the value is reduced.

I am able to get a copy over using the old exp/imp methods (export the table from remote, import it back in), which runs much faster, but this is fairly manual for my automated report.  I have considered trying to write a pipelined function to select this data from, using it to split the CLOBS into BYTE/VARCHAR2 chunks (with an additional chunk number column), but didn't want to do this if someone had tried it and found a problem.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get better performance when increasing arraysize to 1500 or higher. See also attached document: http://www.fors.com/velpuri2/PERFORMANCE/SQLNET.pdf